# Responsive position absolute DIV with Javascript

Tags: javascript, position, responsiveness

I have a div with text that is positioned over a photo. I wrote some JS that ensures that if the div is greater than 500px in height, the position goes back to inherit.

It works as when I look at the page on my phone or Ipad, the DIV is well positioned.

However, when I reduce the browser on my computer, the Javascript only works if I refresh the page. I would like it to be responsive as I reduce my screen size. I realize that my javascript isn't taking account the movement of the screensize changing.

I'm fairly new to Javscript so I'm a bit stuck.

```js
parentHeight = document.getElementById('boxinside').offsetHeight;
  if (parentHeight > 500){
    console.log(parentHeight)
    document.querySelector('#boxinside').style.position = "inherit";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#boxinside').style.position = "absolute";
  }
```

```css
body {
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  }
  p {
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}


.parallax-window {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: 50% 50%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 500px;
  }
}


.text {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  h3 {
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    @include from-medium {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  }
    font-family: 'Lato';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 0px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    @include from-medium-low {
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
}


.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  a {
    color: #5B1B14;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color:#5B1B14;
  }
}

.photo-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  @include from-medium-low {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: inherit;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}

.container-macaron {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-text {
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  h2 {
    color: #5B1B14;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

#boxinside {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  left: 420px;
p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
}

.photo {
  // img {
  // position: relative;
  // }
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590080876351-941da357bde6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2960&q=80" alt="Italian Trulli">
    <div class="text">
      <p>ABOUT US</p>
      <h3>Good quality baking<br> for a reasonable price</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-macaron">
  <div class="photo-left">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590080876351-941da357bde6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2960&q=80" alt="Italian Trulli" height='550px'>
    </div>
    <div class="text-box">
      <div class="header-text">
        <h1>Benjamin Pallais</h1>
        <h2 style='color:#5B1B14;'>Founder of Monsieur Macaron</h2>
      </div>
      <div id='boxinside'>
        <div class='boxtext'>
          <p class='question'><b>Who are you?</b></p>
          <p>Bonjour, I am Benjamin. Creator of Monsieur Macaron, foodie, and ex rugby player.</p>
          <br>
          <p class='question'><b>Why did you chose New Zealand?</b></p>
          <p>Probably, for the love of rugby and the attractions around the myth of the All Blacks. I first visited New Zealand in 2007, when I was 21 years old. Since that trip, I have been motivated to become a Kiwi.</p>
          <br>
          <p class='question'><b>Why did you become a Pastry chef?</b></p>
          <p>Probably the best job to express myself creatively with my patisserie, to allow me to travel around the world, and to provide happiness to my customers.</p>
          <br>
          <p class='question'><b>Why have you created Monsieur Macaron Ltd? Why did you choose macarons?</b></p>
          <p>In my opinion, Macarons are the most glamorous biscuit in the world. As a Parisien, the macaron is the most trendy patisserie and is well known to Kiwi people. The creation of the company gave me the opportunity to fully express myself, manage my own relationships with customers/partners, and have the honour of helping the NZ Food culture.</p>
          <br>
          <p class='question'><b>What's the best part of your job?</b></p>
          <p>Having the pleasure to sell my pasteries and meet my customers at the Farmers Market in Hastings every Sunday.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to detect window resizing:

```
function changePosition() {
  let parentHeight = document.getElementById('boxinside').offsetHeight;
  if (parentHeight > 500){
    console.log(parentHeight)
    document.querySelector('#boxinside').style.position = "inherit";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#boxinside').style.position = "absolute";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  changePosition();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
   changePosition();
});
```